# Not able to connect Azure Postgres db from groovy snippet

Tags: java, postgresql, groovy, jenkins-groovy, azure-postgresql

I've Jenkins job to run groovy script which will import some data on Azure Postgres db. Here is my groovy part of postgress connectivity. I've added all the dependency classes in the groovy script.

```
def driver = Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver').newInstance() as Driver
def props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("DB_user", "admin@sample-prod-eastus2")
props.setProperty("DB_password", "HmSaSx5aX")
def conn = driver.connect("jdbc:postgresql://admin@sample-prod-eastus2.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/db_name?ssl=true", props)
def sql = new Sql(conn)
```

But I'm getting some connection attempt failed. I tried to telnet from my Jenkins server to Azuredb and it has the connectivity. I'm not sure whether its due to Java or something else.

```
Processing DSL script jenkins_jobs.groovy
FATAL: The connection attempt failed.
java.net.UnknownHostException: admin@sample-prod-eastus2.postgres.database.azure.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:81)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:93)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
Caused: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:297)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
at java_sql_Driver$connect.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at jenkins_jobs.run(jenkins_jobs.groovy:14)
at jenkins_jobs$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at jenkins_jobs$run.call(Unknown Source)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScript(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_runScripts_closure1.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2078)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$165.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:351)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Collecting metadata...
Metadata collection done.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I suspect that the admin@ should not be in the connection URL.

Comment: As per Azure Postgres documentation, we need to use the username@host:port_no to connect the db.

Comment: Well ... as per the exception message (!!), the string "admin@" is showing up in the hostname, and that is WRONG.  So why don't you try removing it?

Comment: `As per Azure Postgres documentation, we need to use the username@host:port_no` - where did you get it?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-java

Comment: @StephenC Changed as per your advice and it works!! Thanks much !!